# Extracting Frequency and Amplitude from Mic Sound

Tags: iphone, audio

I am trying to develop an iPhone app that can extract frequency and amplitude from a given sound sample and save it to a text file. I checked the auriotouch program provided by Apple that displays the sound signal as a spectrum.  My question is how to capture the data (Frequency,amplitude) that is used to create the spectrum in a separate text file so that it can be analyzed in MATLAB.

Comment: Why not just skip the plotting in AurioTouch and save the output data from the FFT ?

Comment: I am now extracting magnitude and frequency from the buffered data. My question is whether it can be read in any kind of software such as Matlab to reproduce the sound?

Comment: If you want to *reproduce* the sound then either just save the original time domain samples, or if you really do need the frequency domain data then you will need to save the complex FFT outputs for each bin. Note that MATLAB can do FFTs etc so there is really no need to do this in the app unless you have some other reason to do so.